# Return length of filtered array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filter

I want to show a message if nothing was found matching user input. I'm using [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter).

In this example the variable filteredPages is set, I can get the current length and show the message correctly.

```
<div ng-repeat="page in filteredPages = (pages | filterBy: ['name', 'about', 'location.street', 'location.city', 'location.zip']: search) | orderBy: '-likes'" ng-click="openPage(page)"></div>
{{filteredPages.length}}
<div ng-if="!filteredPages.length">Não foi encontrado nenhuma página com "{{search}}".</div>
```

In this similar example for some reason the variable filteredEvents is always null. So I can't show the message correctly if nothing matching was found.

```
<div ng-repeat="date in events | orderBy:'date'" ng-if="(date.events | filterBy: ['name', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'place.name', 'place.location.street', 'place.location.city', 'place.location.zip']: search).length">
    <div ng-repeat="event in filteredEvents = (date.events | filterBy: ['name', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'place.name', 'place.location.street', 'place.location.city', 'place.location.zip']: search) | orderBy:'-attending_count'" ng-click="openEvent(event)"></div>
</div>
{{filteredEvents.length}}
<div ng-if="!filteredEvents.length">Não foi encontrado nenhum evento com "{{search}}".</div>
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: start by removing any html that doesn't change the outcome and is not relevant for the question

Comment: Can we see how `events` looks like? I am not familia with this syntax `(date.events | filterBy: array)` , where did you find about `filterBy` ?

Comment: https://jsonblob.com/564fd6c4e4b01190df40d351

Comment: The filter is ok, just the message in case nothing matches that I can't get to work.

Comment: Each iteration of the outer ng-repeat, on events, define its own filteredEvents. And you're trying to display filteredEvents.length outside of this outer ng-repeat. So the variable doesn't exist. And even if it did, which of the many filteredEvents would it contain?

Comment: You are right. How can I work around this?